# `wire:model` not letting selected value to be selected

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

A select element with a pre-selected value does not render correctly, if I do not add `wire:model` to the element, it works well and shows the selected value in the select element.
But I need to add `wire:model` to save user-updated data

```
<div class="m-widget4">
@foreach ($this->result as $data)
<div>{{$data->id}}</div>
<select wire:model="list_session_picker.{{ $data->id }}" wire:key="{{ $data->id }}">
       <option value="" disabled hidden>Select Session</option>
       @foreach ($sessionData as $session)
       <option value="{{ $session->id }}">{{ $data->user_session_id == $session->id ? 'selected' : '' }} {{ $session->session }}</option>                                                               
        @endforeach
</select>
@endforeach
</div>
```

**Componenet.php**

```
public $result = [], $list_session_picker = [];
public $search_picker;

public function render()
{
    $data['sessionData'] = Session::all('id', 'session');       
    $data['sectionData'] = Section::all('id', 'section');

    return view('livewire.promote', $data);
}

public function search()
{
    $search = ScCompany::query();

    if (!empty($this->search_picker)) {
        $search->where('session_id', $this->search_picker);
        
        return                 
            $this->result = $search
                ->whereNull('date_of_enter')
                ->with(['session:id,session', 'section:id,name'])
                ->get();
    }
}
```

It works if I remove `wire:model`, so how could I show the selected value while using `wire:model` or is there any other way ?

Note** here i set `wire:model="list_session_picker.{{ $data->id }}"` so the list comes from for each loop can't update each other (on changing the option of one select will not uodate another select element in the list) .

I found [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/show-selected-option-in-livewire-not-working) and [this](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/85) solutions, but how to apply them in my case, not much clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the selected element in the livewire component and not in the view.  The view will reflect the state of the component thanks to the wire model.

At present you have conflicting views of which element should be selected and they will always be at odds with each other.

Just wire model.  If you have an existing item selected, then set it state at the component.

Comment: I got it, I need to update the public property itself from component to view changes in view, but as I have list of select elements loaded from foreach loop with `wire:model:list_session_picker.{{ $data->id }}` , I need a help with workaround how to change the value for each of select element

Comment: add your component to the question

Comment: question updated

Comment: I can't follow your naming.  Use of $result and $data makes it really hard to follow where these items come from and what they contain.  Basically, in your Search method, you need to set elements on the array that correspond with the current state